# Android Studio: is it possible to compile a project with multiple package names

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, package

Is it possible to have a project in Android Studio with the possibility of changing the package name for the app easily, so I can compile it with a package name or with the other (or both at the same time) according to my needs?

Comment: Yes. You should use "build flavors" to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Build Variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) to facilitate this easily.